# How to create a silverlight enabled WCF service in a different project

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services

I want to develop a Silverlight enabled WCF service out of the target web page.

Is it possible ? There is not template in the WCF projects tab.

And if yes how?

Maybe will be possible to create it like usual and then move it (copy it) to a WCF project.

Comment: What did you try yet? Have you already searched on the net and tried to implement something by yourself...? Where did you have any troubles?

Comment: Firstly I built a WCF service library. Then had problems to communicate with silverlight. I suppose that is caused by the binding type but not sure. I searched the net but did not found any good idea.